# How to convert POSIX time to Olson timezone file?

Tags: linux, timezone

I have localzone in POSIX format.

> "PDT,M3.2.0/02:00,M11.1.0/02:00"

How to create my own timezone file with zic tool?

I took an example from man.

rule.infile contains:

> Rule  USA  1970    max    -    Sep   Sun<=14 3:00   0     S

I do

> zic -d . -v rule.infile

but output is empty and no new files around.

What does the option -p do?

Is it possible to use as an input?

it is absolutely unclear from the manual.

**upd:**
The rule file should have three sections: Rule, Zone, Link.

With updated rule.infile the zic is generating a file.

Now I am trying to understand how to define second Sunday.

Comment: The rule files should have three sections: Rule, Zone, Link.

Answer (score 0):

Since I need it for my particular situation I did small bash script.

I know that is not covering all cases. But at least you can use it as an reference.
My task was to parse the string:

> "EST%dEDT%d,M%d.%d.%d/%d:%d,M%d.%d.%d/%d:%d"

example:

> EST5EDT4,M1.3.0/2:00,M11.2.6/2:00

$1 - the POSIX string
$2 - path to the folder for output
$3 - file name for output

```
timezoneposix2olson()
{
    posix=$1
    MONTHS=(ZERO Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec)
    DAYS=(Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat)

    IFS=',' tokens=( $posix )

    # parse EST5EDT4
    tmp=${tokens[0]#*EST}
    no_dst_offset=${tmp%EDT*}
    no_dst_offset=$(( no_dst_offset*-1 ))
    dst_offset=${tokens[0]#*EDT}
    dst_offset=$(( dst_offset*-1 ))

    #parse M1.3.0/2:00
    switch_time1=${tokens[1]#*/}
    temp=${tokens[1]#*M}
    switch_month1=${temp%%.*}
    temp=${tokens[1]#*.}
    switch_week1=${temp%.*}
    temp=${tokens[1]##*.}
    switch_day1=${temp%/*}

    #parse M11.2.6/2:00
    switch_time2=${tokens[2]#*/}
    temp=${tokens[2]#*M}
    switch_month2=${temp%%.*}
    temp=${tokens[2]#*.}
    switch_week2=${temp%.*}
    temp=${tokens[2]##*.}
    switch_day2=${temp%/*}

    if [ $switch_week1 -eq 5 ] ; then
    rule_day1=last${DAYS[$switch_day1]}
    else
    rule_day1=$(( (switch_week1-1)*7+1 ))
    rule_day1="${DAYS[$switch_day1]}>=${rule_day1}"
    fi

    if [ $switch_week2 -eq 5 ] ; then
    rule_day2=last${DAYS[$switch_day2]}
    else
    rule_day2=$(( (switch_week2-1)*7+1 ))
    rule_day2="${DAYS[$switch_day1]}>=${rule_day2}"
    fi

    delta=$((dst_offset - no_dst_offset))
    delta="${delta#-}:00"

    if [ $dst_offset -gt 0 ] ; then
    offset_mod1="+$dst_offset"
    else
    offset_mod1=$dst_offset
    fi

    if [ $no_dst_offset -gt 0 ] ; then
    offset_mod2="+$no_dst_offset"
    else
    offset_mod2=$no_dst_offset
    fi

    local olson_file="$2/$3.zone"
    echo "Rule LOCAL 1996 max - ${MONTHS[$switch_month1]} $rule_day1 $switch_time1 $delta $offset_mod1" > $olson_file

    echo "Rule LOCAL 1996 max - ${MONTHS[$switch_month2]} $rule_day2 $switch_time2 0 $offset_mod2" >> $olson_file

    echo "Zone Localtime $no_dst_offset LOCAL GMT%s" >> $olson_file

    zic -d $2 -v $olson_file
}
```